# Changing nested dictionary in VBA

Tags: vba, dictionary, nested

I was about to ask a question when the solution came in one test. So I'm posting anyway and answering, so others can benefit.

**The question was:**

I run the code below and get a runtime error 450 - Wrong number of arguments or invalid property assignment

```
Dim data, tmpDict As Dictionary
Set data = New Dictionary
Set tmpDict = New Dictionary

data.Add 123, tmpDict

Set tmpDict = data.Item(123)
tmpDict.Add "somekey", 100
data.Item(123) = tmpDict
```

The error occur in last line. The code was simplified to focus on changing a nested dictionary in an already existing item.

How can I succeed in this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution can be achieved contracting the last 3 lines in just 1, using:

```
data.Item(123).Add "somekey", 100
```

instead of:

```
Set tmpDict = data.Item(123)
tmpDict.Add "somekey", 100
data.Item(123) = tmpDict
```