# Changing dictionary string item to nested dictionary in VBA

Tags: vba, dictionary, nested

after my [last venture with dictionaries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29659656/changing-nested-dictionary-in-vba) i tried this code:

```
Dim data, tmpDict As Dictionary
Set data = New Dictionary

data.Add "abc", "abc"

Set tmpDict = New Dictionary

data("abc") = tmpDict
```

And got a runtime error

> error 450 - Wrong number of arguments or invalid property assignment

**So, here is my question**: how can I change a dictionary item that is a string to another dictionary, so it becomes nested to the first?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you maybe want to have `tmpDict` as the returning value for the key `abc`? In that case, you should nest since the beginning:

```
Dim data, tmpDict As Dictionary
Set data = New Dictionary
Set tmpDict = New Dictionary
data.Add "abc", tmpDict
```

Or, if you want to keep the structure of your code, you should use the keyword `Set` since you're setting a reference to an object:

```
Dim data, tmpDict As Dictionary
Set data = New Dictionary
data.Add "abc", "abc"
Set tmpDict = New Dictionary
Set data("abc") = tmpDict
```

I confess I might have misunderstood the question, please tell me in that case and I will edit/remove my answer.

Comment: The second alternative solves my problem. Since I'm changing the dictionary value I wouldn't imagine using the keyword Set here.